# In Spring security why does UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter explicitly check HTTP method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've taken a look at the Spring Secuirty UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter and I've noticed they explicitly check for HTTP method in the attemptAuthentication method

```
    private static final AntPathRequestMatcher DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login",
            "POST");

    ...

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        if (this.postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        username = (username != null) ? username.trim() : "";
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        password = (password != null) ? password : "";
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(username,
                password);
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
```

There is an AntMatcher set so it matches POST only, so why the explicit checking in the attemptAuthentication method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` loads username and password information from the request (provided in plain text) and attempts to authenticate the user using these settings.
This is useful for a form-based authentication method.

You can disable this check by using `setPostOnly(false)`, which would allow authentication using different methods.
This, however, does not correlate with the defined routing pattern, as filters are executed before every request that requires authentication.

For security reasons, this check is, by default, enabled.
If disabled (and corresponding routing), you could authenticate via a get-request.
However, get provides the parameters as url-parameters. Therefore, your request would look like this:

`http://my.site/login?user=myuser&password=mypassword`

It's common for web servers, proxies, CDNs, etc., to log the requested URL.
Therefore, given a get-based authentication method, the user's username and password would be stored in plain-text

Edit:

The reason why the check is needed at all is quite simple.
Spring allows you to specify a custom RequestMatcher yourself.
So you could simply set it to `/api/login` (without specifying the method).
To prevent this error, you must explicitly disable the POST-only check.

To me, the situation sounds like a case of: "We know it's stupid, but you might want to do this anyway". An analogy would be reacts dangerouslySetInnerHTML or apts query ["Yes, I know what I'm doing!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436171)
Basically cases where an action is usually considered unsafe, but you might need it regardless.

Comment: I think the question is more about why you have to configure the HTTP method both through setting the `AntPathRequestMatcher` and the `postOnly` flag. For example, let's say you change the `AntPathRequestMatcher` to allow `GET`, why do you still need to set `postOnly` to `false`.

Comment: But the AntMatcher has the POST method inside of it, meaning GET wont hit this filter and the authentication won't be attempted, so the additional check is not needed, or am I still missing something?

Comment: @ba9c83134a187bb4, I see. The problem is, a filter is technically executed on every request and the AntMatcher can be replaced by the user. I've updated my answer to reflect that.